# Get convex polygon's vertices in clockwise order and get geometric centroid of a convex polygon

Tags: trimesh

In trimesh, how do we get convex polygon's vertices in clockwise order and get geometric centroid of a convex polygon?

There is a mesh.centroid function but I'm not sure if that is exactly the geometric centroid.